# Creating Content Item via Code in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I need to create content item using code. i know there is built in way but i want my own functionality in module. I tried the code but it gives me error. All related code is given below. Content part name is "Course" and Content Item name is "Courses"

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int Id {
get { return ContentItem.Id; }
}

**Controller**

  public ActionResult Create()
    {            
        var course = _orchardService.ContentManager.New("Courses");
        dynamic model = _orchardService.ContentManager.BuildEditor(course);

        return View((object)model);                                  
    }


    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult CreatePOST(string idl)
    {

        var contentItem = _contentManager.New("Courses");

        _contentManager.Create(contentItem, VersionOptions.Draft);

        dynamic model = _contentManager.UpdateEditor(contentItem, this);

        _contentManager.Publish(contentItem);

        _orchardService.Notifier.Information(new LocalizedString("Your content has been created."));

        var adminRouteValues = _contentManager.GetItemMetadata(contentItem).AdminRouteValues;

        return RedirectToRoute(adminRouteValues);
    }


    public ActionResult Index(PagerParameters pagerParameters, CourseSearchVM search)
    {
        //this is displaying only published content
        var courseQuery = _contentManager.Query<CoursePart>().List().ToList();
        // Project the query into a list of customer shapes
        var coursesProjection = from course in courseQuery
                                  select Shape.course
                                  (
                                    Id: course.Id,
                                    Name: course.Name,
                                    Description: course.Description
                                  );

        // The pager is used to apply paging on the query and to create a PagerShape
        var pager = new Pager(_siteService.GetSiteSettings(), pagerParameters.Page, pagerParameters.PageSize);
        // Apply paging
        var coures = coursesProjection.Skip(pager.GetStartIndex()).Take(pager.PageSize);
        // Construct a Pager shape
        var pagerShape = Shape.Pager(pager).TotalItemCount(courseQuery.Count());
        // Create the viewmodel
        var model = new CourseIndexVM(coures, search, pagerShape);
        return View(model);
    }


**CoursePart Model**

public class CoursePart : ContentPart<CoursePartRecord>
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return Record.Name; }
        set { Record.Name = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return Record.Description; }
        set { Record.Description = value; }
    }
}

public class CoursePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}


**Create.cshtml**

@{ Layout.Title = "Edit Course"; }

@using(Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost())
{
@Display(Model)
}

 **Course.cshtml**

 @model Course.Models.CoursePart
 <fieldset> 
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see which line the exception is thrown on? I think .As<>() returns null if the content item does not have the content part you are trying to cast to, which would cause the NullReferenceException when you attempt to set the name and description, so check to see if you content type has that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to Cast a ContentItem to a ContentPart. That won't work, instead of that in your createPost action you should call to contentManger.UpdateEditor method. In order to do that, you should implement IUpdateModel interface. Take a look to AdminController on Orchard.Core/Contents/Controller.

BTW this weekend I will release a module which enables custom editors on the front end.

Comment: I exactly did what you said but still gets the same error. strange thing is that i copied the same code which is used to create content in orchard. I modified my original post for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its working now. i just changed the parameter to (string id)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, it would help to know what line you got the error on and what item was null.

That being said, to answer your initial question, **how to create a content item from your code:**

```
var item = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("Course");
var part = item.As<CoursePart>();
part.Name = "SomeName";
part.Description = "SomeDescription";
_orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(item);
```

However as stated by jmgomez you don't normally have to do this.
I would suggest you read this part of the documentation:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part

And possibly have a look at this tutorial:
http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1

For help using the pager, you may want to have a look at this:
http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-10